# How to copy OCR text data to a new pdf Itext 7 C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a scanned document. In this document there is the transparent layer of text and image on it. Is there a way to copy text as it is (with no changes,so it remains transparent and on the same position ) to another .pdf what I created(without images)? I searched for it in google, and didn't find any solutions. I know that I can copy text from the pages to string, then add it to my new document with a new paragraph. But it will destroy transparency and locations of recognized letters.  What I really want to do is change the image beneath OCR text. And firstly the idea was to remove all images from .pdf and add new images. Then I understood that it is not a good idea and not very easy to do as there is a lot of different image types.(but I did it this way, look on to solution)

Adding samples:

My sample document is scanned document in which I did OCR.

[Sample document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k3Ghbw5uDH-ziGQw7PBtvbtj-BcACsf4/view?usp=sharing)

My real code sample is here:

```
                    String dest = "C:\\ImagePaged.pdf";
                    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
                   
                    // Creating a PdfDocument  
                    pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
                    

                    // Creating a Document   Document 
                    iText.Layout.Document document2 = new iText.Layout.Document(pdfDoc);
                    document2.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

                    //////////////////////

                    List<int> rotatedPages = new List<int>();
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\\source.pdf", FileMode.Open))
                 
                    using (Document document = new Document(fs)) // this object represents a PDF document
                    
                    {

                
                        // process and save pages one by one
                        for (int i = 0; i < document.Pages.Count; i++)
                        {
                     

       
                            Page currentPage = document.Pages[i];
                            
                            // we use original page's width and height for image as well as default rendering settings
                            using (Bitmap bitmap = currentPage.Render((int)currentPage.Width*3, (int)currentPage.Height*3, new RenderingSettings()))
                          
                            {
                                if (bitmap.Width>bitmap.Height)
                                {
                                    rotatedPages.Add(i+1);

                                    bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);

                                }
                                

 bitmap.Save($"C:\\ImagePage{i}.png", ImageFormat.Png);

iText.IO.Image.ImageData imageData = iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory.Create($"C:\\ImagePage{i}.png");

 Image image = new Image(imageData);
                             
imageData = null;
             
                                
   document2.Add(image);
                                
     image = null;
     File.Delete($"C:\\ImagePage{i}.png");


                                


                            }
                            GC.Collect();
                        }
                        document.Dispose();
                        document2.Close();
                        GC.Collect();
```

UPDATE:SOLUTION

Thanks to code part provided from mkl I was able to build up the solution.

1. I used Apitron to generate images from my watermarked pdf for every page(look up for code sample).
2. I used code provided by mkl, to delete all images from my original pdf document.
3. I used Itext to add images created by Apitron to pdf file created in clause nr.2.

I won´t post here my entire solution, but important things to keep in mind while doing it are:

a. Set margins in your destination document like this:

> document2.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

b. Rotate your image before adding it.

```
 int rotations=  pdfDoc.GetPage(i+1).GetRotation();
                            
                                if (rotations>0)
                                {
                                   

                                    if (rotations == 270)
                                    {
                                        bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipXY);
                                    } else
                                          if (rotations == 90)
                                    {
                                        bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);
                                    }
                                    if (rotations == 180)
                                    {
                                        bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipXY);
                                    }
```

c. Create image with added page number.

```
image = new Image(imageData).SetFixedPosition(i + 1, 0, 0).SetAutoScale(true);   (the first argument i, is the page number)
```

Comment: How about simply copying the original page as is and then replacing the image Xobjects in question?

Comment: Yes. I should try it. But there might be a slight problem. What if there will be few images on one page. I cant replace them, because I never get it right. So the solution may be deleting all images from page and add my new one. But if I just add my new on is it going behind OCR text on the right place or not, thats the questin. I will try it tomrrow.

Comment: @mkl I found a code to replace images, but do you have an idea how to delete all image Xobjects from page? I tried write a null in Xobject but id didn't do the thing.  PdfDictionary pageDict = pdfDoc.GetFirstPage().GetPdfObject();
            PdfDictionary resources = pageDict.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.Resources);
            PdfDictionary xObjects = resources.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.XObject);

Comment: If you set those Xobjects to null or remove the entries completely, your pdf strictly speaking becomes invalid as is content stream references a non-existing or null Xobject. Better set it to a form Xobject without any instructions.

Comment: Can you please show how to do that. I updated my code, please have a look. I think that I don't know how to make a new proper empty Xobject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments I proposed to replace the image XObjects with *a form Xobject without any instructions.* You tried to use a plain `PdfDictionary` for this but that is too plain. Instead try a method like this using the PDF object underneath an empty `PdfFormXObject` as `replacement`:

```c#
void replaceImages(PdfResources pdfResources, PdfObject replacement)
{
    PdfDictionary xobjects = pdfResources.GetPdfObject().GetAsDictionary(PdfName.XObject);
    if (xobjects == null)
        return;
    ISet<PdfName> toReplace = new HashSet<PdfName>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<PdfName, PdfObject> entry in xobjects.EntrySet())
    {
        PdfObject pdfObject = entry.Value;
        if (pdfObject is PdfIndirectReference reference)
            pdfObject = reference.GetRefersTo();
        if (pdfObject is PdfStream pdfStream && PdfName.Image.Equals(pdfStream.GetAsName(PdfName.Subtype)))
        {
            toReplace.Add(entry.Key);
        }
    }
    foreach (PdfName name in toReplace)
    {
        xobjects.Put(name, replacement);
    }
}
```

*([ReplaceImageWithEmptyObject](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/csharp/content/ReplaceImageWithEmptyObject.cs#L41) helper method)*

Beware, this changes the actual resources without updating the internal cache of the `PdfResources` instance. Thus, its state may become inconsistent and you shouldn't use that instance for other operations.

You can apply it to a `PdfDocument pdfDocument` like this:

```c#
PdfFormXObject replacement = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(1, 1));
for (int pageNr = 1; pageNr <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); pageNr++)
{
    PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDocument.GetPage(pageNr);
    PdfResources pdfResources = pdfPage.GetResources();
    replaceImages(pdfResources, replacement.GetPdfObject());
}
```

*([ReplaceImageWithEmptyObject](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/csharp/content/ReplaceImageWithEmptyObject.cs#L21) test `testReplaceForVZ`)*

It works as expected with your example PDF.

Comment: Hello mkl. It is working thanks. I was able to build my solution from your code here. I will leave you +1, but I won't mark your answer as solution because it is only half of it. Tho I will update my answer with my solution.

Comment: I see that you have edited your solution into your question. Please don't do that but instead create an answer of your own for that. On stack overflow questions strictly are meant for the problems and answers for the solutions. Furthermore, you can accept that answer eventually...